# Is it possible to use public XMPP servers to create private chat rooms?

Tags: java, chat, xmpp, instant-messaging

We are developing web application to manage associations, that is we have multiple associations and we should be able to create 1 room (or group) per association
and programmatically log users on the room so they cannot pretend to be other person. Web application is being developed using GWT.
We don't want to maintain our own xmpp server so the question is: is above possible with one of public services here http://xmpp.org/resources/public-services/ ?
Sorry if it is dumb question, i am fairly new to IM/XMPP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Multi-user-Chat-over-XMPP standard](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html) supports password-protected chat rooms (i.e., you need a secret to join) and members-only chat rooms, either of which would be what you're after, but I don't know whether any of the listed services actually allows you to create them. I'd imagine that public servers would want to be rather careful with such things given the potential to use them for malicious purposes.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any third party chat rooms i can integrate into my website? XMPP is not a must, can be any third party chat room with the ability to create multiple private chat rooms/groups.

Comment: @Zhaidarbek: No idea at all. That particular question is probably better off asked on serverfault.com, since it's about deployments and not programming.